# QTreeView::dropMimeData - setting values for a new child

Tags: qt

I am trying to drop some mime encoded text onto a tree view.  It is working - the dropMimeData() method is called, I can decode the mime data into the strings that were dropped, I can insert a child into the model which shows up in the view, but ... I can't find a way to set the text value of the new item/row to the string dragged and dropped (or any string for that matter).

Here is some of the code i've tried inside the dropMimeData() method:

```
if ( ( row == -1) && (column == -1) && parent.isValid() ) {
   int mdlidx = this->data(parent, Qt::DisplayRole).ModelIndex;
   qDebug() << "mdlidx: " << mdlidx;

   // treet text - the text of the cell that gets dropped onto
   QString tt = this->data(parent, Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
   qDebug() << "tree text: " << tt;

   TreeItem *item = this->getItem(parent);

   int ccnt = item->childCount();
   qDebug() << "ccnt: " << ccnt ;

   if ( item->insertChildren(0, 1, 0) ) {
       qDebug() << "Child Inserted";

       // how do I access the new child item here ???
   } else {
       qDebug() << "Failed";
   }
```

How do I access the new child item in order to set the text that would be visible in the view?

I'm using the QStandardItemModel, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this is to create a signal and slot - I emot the signal in the dropMimeData() method and the slot is in a part of the code that has the view and model, so can easily update the model.

I send the mime data and the parent across using the signal.

I'm not sure if this is the correct way of doing this, but it is working.